# jQuery pause the scrolling div on hover

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using a wordpress plugin that scrolls posts to infinite.
I want that when I hover on the post, scroll shall stop.
 I tried using

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.spe_div').hover(function()
        {
            spe_scrollOn='false';
        },function()
        {
            spe_scrollOn='true';
            spe_content();
        }
    );

});
</script>
```

name of plugin that i have used is wordpress scroll excerpt plugin.

ANy help is really appreciated.

Comment: can you post a link to the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and this is what I came up with to get a pause on hover to work, I also tooko the time to correct the "hiccup" or stutter that the scroll effect has when is at the top of it's scroll (would jump several pixels and didn't look smooth).

**Changes to scroll-post-excerpt.php:**

Line 72:

change

```
$dis_num_height = $dis_num_height + 4;
```

to

```
$dis_num_height = $dis_num_height;
```

(That fixes the stutter, basically the change is to remove the + 4 from the end of the line)

Insert a new line at line 97, add this code:

```
var spe_Pause = false;
```

Insert this code in to the spe_createscroll() function, I inserted it at line 104

```
// Add Hover detection for pausing
jQuery(spe_obj).hover(function(){spe_Pause = true;}, function(){spe_Pause = false;});
```

And the last edit for this file was to ensure that jQuery was loaded before this script file, to do that I modified the wp_enqueue_script code (now at line 198):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scroll-post-excerpt', get_option('siteurl').'/wp-content/plugins/scroll-post-excerpt/scroll-post-excerpt.js',array( 'jquery' ));
```

(Note the additional parameter passed at the end of the function `array( 'jquery')`, this is what causes the script to wait.

**Changes to scroll-post-excerpt.js:**

I ended up making a few changes to the function spe_scroll(), modified code to this:

```
function spe_scroll() {
    if(spe_Pause == true) {
        setTimeout("spe_scroll()",15);
        return;
    }
    spe_obj.scrollTop = spe_obj.scrollTop + 1;
    spe_scrollPos++;
    //if ((spe_scrollPos%spe_heightOfElm) == 0) {
    if (spe_obj.scrollTop == spe_heightOfElm) {
        spe_scrollPos = 0;
        spe_numScrolls--;
        if (spe_numScrolls == 0) {
            spe_obj.scrollTop = '0';
            spe_content();
        } else {
            if (spe_scrollOn == 'true') {
                spe_content();
            }
        }
    } else {
        setTimeout("spe_scroll();", 15);
    }
}
```

To break it down, I first inserted

```
if(spe_Pause == true) {
        setTimeout("spe_scroll()",15);
        return;
    }
```

This will check the hover parameter added in the modification to the first file and perform an early function exit with a reset to check for when the user has moved out.

Then I modified the if() statement, didn't see the need for the modulus method, so I modified it to test for the current scrollTop of the element

```
if (spe_obj.scrollTop == spe_heightOfElm) {
```

(you could use the spe_scrollPos variable if you preferred).

Inside the if() statement I added a line to reset the value of the spe_scrollPos variable,

```
spe_scrollPos = 0;
```

as this just keeps counting up and IMHO, not a good idea as it will just keep consuming memory.

I also modified the speed of the scroll by changing the timeout value to 15, your call on what speed you want.

Hope that helps!